# Extend Complex Type from Imported XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to extend a complex type from an imported XSD.  This is to mimic a base/inherited class structure.  Right now my base xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="BaseGrammar"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd"
           xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="BaseGrammar">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Grammar">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and my child xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="TableGrammar"
               targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               elementFormDefault="qualified"
               xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd" schemaLocation="BaseGrammar.xsd" />    

    <xs:complexType name="TableGrammar">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BaseGrammar">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="parameters" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I get an error stating that it cannot find the definition of "BaseGrammar."  I'm assuming it has something to do with the namespaces, however; I'm still a bit fuzzy on how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of namespaces.
You define the `TableGrammar` type in the namespace:

```
http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd
```

which is the target namespace of your first schema, but reference to it in the namespace:

```
http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd
```

which is declared not only as the target namespace of your second schema, but also as the default namespace for that XSD document as a whole (XSD is also an XML document). That you do by this setting:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
```

But according to XSD language, the value of `base` attribute is a qualified name. That means that when the namespace is not specified explicitly (with a prefix), it will be resolved according to the default namespace actual at that location.

Your second schema can be fixed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="TableGrammar"
               targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               elementFormDefault="qualified"
               xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/TableGrammar.xsd"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:bg="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd">

    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd" schemaLocation="BaseGrammar.xsd" />    

    <xs:complexType name="TableGrammar">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="bg:BaseGrammar">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="parameters" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here, `bg` prefix is declared in `<xs:schema>` to reference to `http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd` namespace. Then, it is used in the `base` attribute to specify the actual namespace of `BaseGrammar` name explicitly.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error on `<xs:extension base="bg:BaseGrammar">`: "Namespace http://tempuri.org/BaseGrammar.xsd is not available to be referenced in this schema".